# Rxjs operators bundled two times after migration to Angular 5

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-cli

Recently my team migrated an Angular 4 project to Angular 5. Also in this migration we started using Angular cli. Everything is ok, the project is working and we finally managed to reduce the bundle size (aot, tree shaking, build-optimizer, etc.).

The only problem is that in the final bundle, the rxjs seems to be included two times ([bundle analyzer screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v39a6.png)).

Of course we changed all Observable imports to

```
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
```

Any ideas?

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "app",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json --port 8080",
    "dev": "ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json --port 8080",
    "build": "ng build --prod --aot --build-optimizer --vendor-chunk=true --base-href /app/ --deploy-url /app/",
    "build-report": "bash ./scripts/ng.sh build --prod --aot --build-optimizer --vendor-chunk=true --stats-json --base-href /app --deploy-url /app",
    "report": "webpack-bundle-analyzer dist/stats.json",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "clean": "rm -rf ./node_modules",
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@agm/core": "^1.0.0-beta.2",
    "@angular/animations": "5.0.4",
    "@angular/common": "5.0.4",
    "@angular/compiler": "5.0.4",
    "@angular/core": "5.0.4",
    "@angular/forms": "5.0.4",
    "@angular/http": "5.0.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "5.0.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "5.0.4",
    "@angular/router": "5.0.4",
    "@angular-redux/store": "7.0.1",
    "@angular-redux/router": "7.0.0",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "9.0.1",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "2.0.0",
    "angular-calendar": "0.21.2",
    "angular-weather-widget": "1.2.4",
    "angular2-highcharts": "0.5.5",
    "angular2-prettyjson": "2.0.6",
    "angular2-signaturepad": "2.4.0",
    "angular2-toaster": "3.0.1",
    "angularfire2": "4.0.0-rc.0",
    "core-js": "2.4.1",
    "firebase": "3.9.0",
    "highcharts-more": "0.1.2",
    "iban": "0.0.8",
    "immutable": "3.8.1",
    "keycloak": "1.2.0",
    "mydatepicker": "2.0.6",
    "ng2-charts": "1.5.0",
    "ng2-dragula": "1.5.0",
    "ng2-file-upload": "1.2.1",
    "ng2-slim-loading-bar": "4.0.0",
    "ng2-vis": "0.0.6",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "2.0.0-beta.8",
    "ngx-perfect-scrollbar": "5.0.5",
    "ng2-responsive": "0.8.4",
    "redux": "3.7.2",
    "redux-devtools": "3.4.1",
    "redux-logger": "3.0.6",
    "redux-observable": "0.17.0",
    "rxjs": "5.5.2",
    "zone.js": "0.8.14"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.5.5",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "5.0.4",
    "@angular/language-service": "5.0.4",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.5.53",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "~3.2.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.6.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.1.0",
    "karma": "~1.7.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.1.1",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.1.2",
    "ts-node": "~3.2.0",
    "tslint": "~5.7.0",
    "typescript": "2.4.2",
    "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "2.9.1"
  }
}
```

**.angular-cli.json**

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "project": {
    "name": "appcli"
  },
  "apps": [
    {
      "root": "src",
      "outDir": "dist",
      "assets": [
        "assets",
        "favicon.ico"
      ],
      "index": "index.html",
      "main": "main.ts",
      "polyfills": "polyfills.ts",
      "test": "test.ts",
      "tsconfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
      "testTsconfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
      "prefix": "app",
      "styles": [
        "styles.css"
      ],
      "scripts": [],
      "environmentSource": "environments/environment.ts",
      "environments": {
        "dev": "environments/environment.ts",
        "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts"
      }
    }
  ],
  "e2e": {
    "protractor": {
      "config": "./protractor.conf.js"
    }
  },
  "lint": [
    {
      "project": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
      "exclude": "**/node_modules/**"
    },
    {
      "project": "src/tsconfig.spec.json",
      "exclude": "**/node_modules/**"
    },
    {
      "project": "e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json",
      "exclude": "**/node_modules/**"
    }
  ],
  "test": {
    "karma": {
      "config": "./karma.conf.js"
    }
  },
  "defaults": {
    "styleExt": "css",
    "component": {}
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This was recently largely debated on rxjs GitHub. For full discussion see https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/issues/3018.

The recommended way of importing operators in RxJS 5.5 is from `rxjs/operators`. For example:

```
import { map, filter, mergeMap, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';
```

However, there a few things to be aware of:

- You need to be using at least `angular-cli@1.5.0`. this is the important part of the code https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/1.5.x/packages/@angular/cli/models/webpack-configs/common.ts#L177-L186.
- I think the unused operators are removed only when creating production build with `-prod`.
- Make sure you're not importing from neither `rxjs` nor `rxjs/Rx`.